# Trading directly in Japanese market

Tags: trading, stock-markets

I would like to trade at night (EST) in the Japanese market.

1. Do I need to read Japanese?
2. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Any large stockbroker will offer trading on all major international markets, including Japan.

You should be aware that trading international securities will incur larger commission charges than trading domestic securities.  For example, my HSBC account will charge 0.5% commission on international securities when trading under $10,000.  Above $10,000 the commission is reduced, but still much larger than the $6.88 charged on any North American market regardless of the size of the trade.

Also, some international markets have additional trading costs.  For example, trading on the London Market carries an additional "stamp duty" of 0.5%.  Also, you may have to complete and file paper work with the national securities regulator as a foreign national.

There is no need to read Japanese unless you wish to read Japanese market analysis. English language analysis of the Japanese market is widely available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, you are saying that any large broker will offer trading in Japan, in real time, (evenings EST)?

Comment: @JackWidman Yes, trading will be done during normal Tokyo market hours.  All you should need is an online account and enough coffee to keep you awake all night.  Your broker should provide you will all the tools you need and any paper work required for filing with the foreign stock exchange or regulator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reading Japanese is necessary to understand news and other reports. If you just work off data, you would be able to do it without knowing the language.
2. Retail brokers like Interactive Brokers offer trading in Japanese futures and equities.